# Mazda Axela 2009 Pioneer C9P5 Head Unit

Tags: electrical, mazda-3, head-unit

My car is a Mazda Axela 2009,it has a Pioneer C9P5 Head Unit installed; a flat battery has wiped the settings for the backing camera, how do I restore it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I was unable to find information about this "C9P5" unit. Is this factory installed unit or aftermarket?

Answer (score 2):

Your reverse camera is in "off" state. Go to Navigation and press menu, there are several option, go to "others" and you will find the camera settings. Use google translate and use the camera to translate the Japanese language to English.